does RealVNC supports XInputExtension version 2?
I have a virtual display provided by RealVNC (VNC(R) Server 6.10.0 (r47347) x64 (Jun 29 2022 12:52:22)),
One program that I launched on it failed with an error : "x input 2 (or newer) is not available". After investigation (xdpyinfo -ext XInputExtension), I discovered that this virtual display was stuck with version 1.3.
I do not know very well RealVNC and the documentation about extensions is very weak. Do you know how to configure RealVNC to support x input 2 ?
Or does this mean that RealVNC is an old product poorly maintained and that I should switch to another product.

Are you using the latest version of RealVNC? If you do, try TigerVNC.
